# My deflater class works incorecctly

Tags: java, compression, deflate

My compression class works incorrectly. When i am trying to compress simple file that contains sentence "something", compressed and uncompressed returns something other. Here is my deflating code:

```
public static void inflate(String arg) throws Exception {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(arg);
            InflaterInputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(fin);

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("def.txt");

            int i;
            while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
                fout.write((byte) i);
                fout.flush();
            }

            fin.close();
            fout.close();
            in.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        new File(arg).delete();
        new File("def.txt").renameTo(new File(arg));
    }

    public static void deflate(String arg) throws Exception {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(arg);

            FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("def.txt");
            DeflaterOutputStream out = new DeflaterOutputStream(fout);

            int i;
            while ((i = fin.read()) != -1) {
                out.write((byte) i);
                out.flush();
            }

            fin.close();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        new File(arg).delete();
        new File("def.txt").renameTo(new File(arg));

    }
```

I call it using

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Main.deflate(args[0]);
            Main.inflate(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So how to fix my code? I think that problem is not in deflating code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does seem to work as expected.

Running it on a text file containing the word 'something' returns an identical file.
To confirm that the output is the same, try editing the following lines:

```java
Test.inflate("def.txt");
```

which is in your main function and

```java
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("output.txt");
```

from your inflate function.

Then comment out the following lines in both your deflate() and inflate() functions

```java
//new File(arg).delete();
//new File("def.txt").renameTo(new File(arg));
```

The program will now take an input file, I used *input.txt* with the word 'something' as per your example, and create a deflated file *def.txt* and an *output.txt* file that is created by inflating *def.txt*.

The output file should match the input file exactly, while the deflated file should be different. If not, there must be some further information about the program that is missing.

Comment: I have tried commenting it, but it returns me empty file.